# SQL UPDATE, only if subselect is not null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a correlated subselect. I use `(...)` for simplicity:

```
UPDATE mytable
 SET col = (...)
 WHERE (...) IS NOT NULL
```

I guess the query is slow because the subselect gets used twice.

Is there a way to run this query and use the subselect only once?

I use PostgreSQL 11

Comment: More information is needed.  Is it a correlated subquery, for instance?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, it is a correlated subquery

Comment: So you want all the rows to have some value if query result is not null? If (...) contains filter from mytable beeing updated you can rewrite the query using UPDATE ... FROM (...) syntax.

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis the subselect is correlated. It uses values of the row. In my case the  new value will be different for most rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a `join` with a primary key:

```
update mytable t
    set col = tt.new_col
    from (select tt.*, ( . . . ) as new_col
          from mytable tt
         ) tt
    where tt.pk = t.pk and new_col is not null;
```

Comment: thank you! BTW, your profile points to and old version of your book. Amazon tells me that there is a new version available.